# Peeking at stdin using match

Tags: parsing, rust

I'm trying to port a translator/parser example from an old compiler textbook from C into Rust.

I have the following code:

```
use std::io::Read;

fn lexan() {
    let mut input = std::io::stdin().bytes().peekable();
    loop {
        match input.peek() {
            Some(&ch) => {
                match ch {
                    _ => println!("{:?}", input.next()),
                }
            }
            None => break,
        }
    }
}
```

At this point I'm not actively trying to parse the input, just get my head around how `match` works. The aim is to add parse branches to the inner match. Unfortunately this fails to compile because I appear to fail in understanding the semantics of match:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |             Some(&ch) => {
  |                  ^--
  |                  ||
  |                  |hint: to prevent move, use `ref ch` or `ref mut ch`
  |                  cannot move out of borrowed content
```

From what I understand, this error is because I don't own the return value of the `match`. The thing is, I don't believe that I'm using the return value of either match. I thought perhaps `input.next()` may have been the issue, but the same error occurs with or without this part (or indeed, the entire println! call).

What am I missing here? It's been some time since I looked at Rust (and never in a serious level of effort), and most of the search results for things of this nature appear to be out of date.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the compiler suggested? What was insufficient about that?

Comment: I did not since I don't expect `ch` should be considered mutable here. making the change however seems to shift the issue further up in the code.

Comment: If I were you, I'd read all the inputs into memory and then iterate over *that* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with the return value of `match`, or even `match` itself::

```
use std::io::Read;

fn lexan() {
    let mut input = std::io::stdin().bytes().peekable();
    if let Some(&ch) = input.peek() {}
}
```

The issue is that you are attempting to bind the result of [`Peekable::peek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html#method.peek)  *while dereferencing it* (that's what the `&` in `&ch` does). In this case, the return type is an `Option<&Result<u8, std::io::Error>>` because the `Bytes` iterator returns errors from the underlying stream. Since this type does not implement `Copy`, trying to dereference the type requires that you transfer ownership of the value. You cannot do so as you don't own the original value — thus the error message.

The piece that causes the inability to copy is the error type of the `Result`. Because of that, you can match one level deeper:

```
match input.peek() {
    Some(&Ok(ch)) => {
        match ch {
            _ => println!("{:?}", input.next()),
        }
    }
    Some(&Err(_)) => panic!(),
    None => break,
}
```

Be aware that this code is pretty close to being uncompilable though. The result of `peek` will be invalidated when `next` is called, so many small changes to this code will trigger the borrow checker to fail the code. I'm actually a bit surprised the above worked on the first go.

If you didn't care about errors at all, you could do

```
while let Some(&Ok(ch)) = input.peek() {
    match ch {
        _ => println!("{:?}", input.next()),
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't split the middle, as this would cause the borrow of `input` to last during the call to `next`:

```
while let Some(x) = input.peek() {
    match *x {
        Ok(ch) => {
            match ch {
                _ => println!("{:?}", input.next()),
            }
        }
        Err(_) => {}
    }

    // Could still use `x` here, compiler doesn't currently see that we don't
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood what the & was doing, but it did not occur to me that a bind was happening in the match (seems obvious now). On your last note: Why would it matter in this case if `peek` is invalidated during the match block? I am looking at `match` as (vaguely) semantically similar to a case, with no fall through. Shouldn't the validity of it be irrelevant after `input.next` is called?

Comment: @user3662805 I added a comment to the last example. TL;DR: that would require *non-lexical lifetimes*, a much-anticipated feature but not one we have now.